# Android - How to call a fragment from inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a fragment that displays Card Views, something like a dashboard. Each Card View should replace the dashboard fragment and call its own fragment when it's clicked, however I can't seem to do it.
I tried the following:

```
imageId.Click += delegate {
                ((FragmentActivity)Activity).ShowFragment(SmokeSensor);
            };
```

The method in the activity:

```
public void ShowFragment(SupportFragment fragment) {
        var transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        connectionStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        if (!ConnectionDetector.IsConnected(this)) {
            connectionStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            transaction.Detach(currentFragment);
            transaction.Commit();
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);

            return;
        }


        if (fragment == currentFragment) {
            transaction.Detach(currentFragment);
            transaction.Attach(currentFragment);
            transaction.Commit();
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);

            return;
        }

        transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in, Resource.Animation.slide_out);
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.Commit();
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(leftDrawer);
        currentFragment = fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a public method in your main activity and call the method to replace or load fragments on an event in your current fragment.

Comment: I did try that, using `((FragmentActivity)Activity).ShowFragment(new SmokeSensor());`, however it throws an error that it `Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' via nested type '*******.Fragments.Dashboard.ViewAdapter`

Comment: you need to call it like this                                               ((youractivityname) getActivity()).yourmethodname();                                              If the problem is still there please paste the method u r trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

For nested fragments use the child fragment manager on you root fragment.

Comment: @Milen http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.ChildFragmentManager/